# h2o flow automl in R throwing error

Tags: r, h2o, automl

I am trying to use h2o automl feature using flow using diabetes dataset that I got from example flows, I am using the version 3.20.0.4 as of now. but the feature doesnot work and throws the below message.appreciate if you can help

"Error calling POSTJSON /99/AutoMLBuilder with opts {"input_spec":{"training_frame":"datase...

ERROR MESSAGE: Field not found: 'keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment' on object water.automl.api.schemas3.AutoMLBuildSpecV99$AutoMLBuildControlV99@32ca26fc"

Comment: I am getting the same error in the newest release and was not before, I think it's a bug. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, that's a bad bug (I reproduced it and it's broken on my end too in 3.20.0.4).  It looks like the bug was introduced a few days ago when we released 3.20.0.4 -- it's only broken on the latest fix release.  I have filed a [bug report](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5811) and we will fix this ASAP.  Thanks for the heads up.

In the meantime, you can use [3.20.0.3](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wright/3/index.html), which I have tested and is working properly.